# PSD files to XCode Free

Tags: xcode, psd

If I have PSD files, can I just simply export every layer as a png and then add to Xcode, or is there a simpler way to do this? I know there are 3rd party programs, but they cost. Is there a way to do it for free? Cheers.

Comment: I don't think there are free alternatives. You have to export it and import it to assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add each image that you want to use as an asset to Xcode, you can´t import a PSD file to Xcode... So export from PSD > Import to Xcode.

Comment: So do I need to save every layer as png?

Comment: Yes if you need to add them layer for layer in you app.